# C2512 Error Using ref classes

Tags: .net, c++-cli

this is definitely one that has come up a lot - but I think this version is kind of different. I'm getting the following error in my code 
`error C2512: 'DataTypes::DateTime': no appropriate default constructor available`. This error has recently appeared during an upgrade from .NET 2 to .NET4.6

Essentially we have a reference class that looks like the following:

```
public ref class DateTime : DataType {
    public:
        DateTime();
        //just highlighting that the constructor is available in the class and hasn't been missed
}
```

This class inherits off of an interface `DataType` which has a static constructor - looks like this:

```
public interface class DataType {
    static DataType() {
    }
}
```

And then this is all tied up inside another class which is where we were getting the error

```
public ref class DateCounter {
    static DateTime dateTime;
}
```

Now - I've managed to fix the error with the following

```
public ref class DateCounter {
    static DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
}
```

which looks to be forcibly telling it to use this constructor - but as this kind of set up is used quite a lot within the application, it's a large job to go through all of these and amend them.

I was just wondering if anyone was aware of a more elegant solution or could at least give a reason why this would have changed between the two versions of .NET

Edit -
So I've set up a small project which looks like it is doing the same thing. There's three files in the project -
TestClass.h:

```
public ref class TestClass : TestInterface {
    protected:
        static int staticItem = 0;
        int holdInt;
    public:
        virtual void Clear();
        TestClass();
        static TestClass();
        TestClass(int takeIn);
        TestClass(TestClass% value);
        TestClass% operator= (TestClass% input);
};
```

TestClassMethods.h:

```
TestClass::TestClass() {

}

TestClass::TestClass(int takeIn) {
    this->holdInt = takeIn;
}

TestClass::TestClass(TestClass% value) {
    *this = value;
}

void TestClass::Clear() {
    this->holdInt = 0;
}

TestClass% TestClass::operator= (TestClass% toAssign) {
    this->holdInt = toAssign.holdInt;

    return *this;
}
```

And ClassLibrary1.cpp

```
namespace TestNamespace {
    ref class TestClass;

    public interface class TestInterface {
        void Clear();
    };

    public ref class Counter {
        static TestClass counterVariable;
    };
}
```

These replicate how the definitions of the code is set up in the application I'm working on and should produce the issue in question

Comment: This is not C++. It looks like Microsoft's C++/CX or something (rebranded C++/CLI?).

Comment: Yes that would be correct - it's the C++ CLI - I'll update the tag

Comment: I had a similar concept, but I was told the CLR does not support static interface definition. And there is no real constraint for your class to implement any static constructor. But you may just need this: `static DateTime^ dateTime;` or Search for 'value types' ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919032/where-is-this-managed-object-stored/8920544#8920544)).  Temporary undeleted my similar issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085770/is-there-some-easy-workaround-to-the-compile-error-c3232). There was some useful comments below.

Comment: Your example works fine in .NET 4.6 before your fix. Can you give an examples that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you call the default (parameterless) destructor of DateTime, which is a value type. The default constructor of value types is implicitly defined and sets an instance of this type to its default value.

So to get rid of this error message, the easiest workaround would be to use one of the parameterized constructors, e.g. "new DateTime (0)", which yields the same value as the default constructor. Another option worth trying is using the special "stack sematics" syntax of C++/CLI, which does all construction/destruction work transparently. To this end, declare the DateTime instance just like a local C++ variable:

```
DateTime vDateTime;
```

Note that the empty parentheses must not be specified in this case. The C++ compiler will recognize this as a default constructor invocation. The parameterized declaration would go like that - now with required parentheses:

```
DateTime vDateTime (0);
```